# Can we use GWT RPC Servlet as Oauth callback URL?

Tags: java, gwt

I am thinking if its possible to user a GWT RPC Servlet (like MyServiceImpl) as callback URL for oauth? The oauth provider will call the callback URL and then pass URL parameters to that callback, is it possible that capture those URL parameter in the RPC servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do something like this.  `RemoteServlet` is just another normal servlet, you can override its `doPost()` and `doGet()` methods. You will just need to filter incoming requests, if it is an Oauth callback handle it, if it is GWT-RPC request (you can find this out by checking for specific GWT HTTP headers), just delegate it to the super class.

But in reality it is better to keep those two things separated. There can't be a real reason why one servlet should be handling Oauth callbacks and GWT-RPC requests.

Answer (score 1):

The deserialization that GWT uses would make this pretty tricky. It also has a lot of restrictions through it's whitelisting of the exact way in which data can be read from the request. You would probably be better off to override the 'service' method and intercept any oauth callbacks before GWT gets to them.

Comment: I guess this technically means that the answer to your question is yes, since your RPC Servlet can handle the request. You just have to snatch it away before GWT tries to parse the request.